# Difference between 'delightful' and 'delighting'?

Tags: word-choice

> "What a terrible football game!"
> "I thought it was ________."
>
> A. delightful
>
> B. delighting
>
> C. delight
>
> D. delighted

I think B is correct but the answer key says A is right. Could you explain why A is the correct one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only ***delightful*** can be used adjectivally with an inanimate object such as a football game. It means *having the quality of causing delight*.

---

***Delighting*** only occurs as a "present continuous" *transitive* verb form (it needs an *object*, someone *who is being delighted*). For example:

> 1: The home team scored in the first five minutes, delighting the fans.
>    2: The home team are delighting the fans with their nimble footwork.

---

***Delighted*** is the *past tense* verb form, either *transitively*...

> 3: The home team's early goal delighted the fans.

...or *intransitively*, with a human (or "anthropomorphised") subject...

> 4: When they scored I was delighted  [(with be-support)](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cowper/AuxInsert.pdf)
>    5: A delighted fan bought me a drink at half-time [(past participial adjective)](http://funeasyenglish.com/american-english-grammar-past-participle-adjective.htm)

---

***Delight*** can be a noun or a verb. As a verb, it's normally used as above, or with "in" *(the home fans delight in seeing their team get off to a good start)*. Other prepositions *(to, at)* are now dated/archaic.

Comment: Will there be any differences if I change your last example into passive voice: the home fans were delighted in seeing their team get off to a good start? And, what does 'get off' mean ? Does it mean to 'leave a place'? Thanks

Comment: @doquan0: My example #4 *is* "passive voice", with *when they scored* effectively acting as an "indirect object". I could have said *"I was delighted **by** their skilful play"*. Or *"I delighted **in** their skilful play"*, using "active voice", but **in** in your version isn't valid (it must be ***by seeing***, or more likely ***to see***). To *get off to/with X* has an idiomatic meaning *to **begin/start** [some process] by doing/using X*